# MySQL: How do I join same table multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I have two tables `ticket` and `attr`. Table `ticket` has `ticked_id` field and several other fields. Table `attr` has 3 fields:

```
ticket_id - numeric
attr_type - numeric
attr_val - string
```

`attr_type` is a fixed enum of values. For example, it can be `1`, `2` or `3`.

I need to make a query, the result of which will be 4 columns:

`ticket_id`, `attr_val` for `attr_type=1`, `attr_val` for `attr_type=2`, `attr_val` for `attr_type=3`

If there is no corresponding value for `attr_type` in `attr` table then NULL value should be  shown in corresponding column.

ticket table :

| ticket_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

attr table :

| ticket_id | attr_type | attr_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Foo |
| 1 | 2 | Bar |
| 1 | 3 | Egg |
| 2 | 2 | Spam |

Expected output :

| ticket_id | attr_val1 | attr_val2 | attr_val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | Bar | Egg |
| 2 | null | Spam | null |
| 3 | null | null | null |

I tried left joining `attr` table 3 times, but cannot figure out how to arrange output by `attr_type`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You need to use multiple `LEFT JOINs`:

```
SELECT 
    ticket.ticket_id,  
    a1.attr_val AS attr_val1,
    a2.attr_val AS attr_val2,
    a3.attr_val AS attr_val3
FROM ticket
    LEFT JOIN attr a1 ON ticket.ticket_id=a1.ticket_id AND a1.attr_type=1
    LEFT JOIN attr a2 ON ticket.ticket_id=a2.ticket_id AND a2.attr_type=2
    LEFT JOIN attr a3 ON ticket.ticket_id=a3.ticket_id AND a3.attr_type=3
```

Here is an example: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34421/3).

Comment: I tried your query, in my similar problem but it is returning same record. Why is that? Where I'm mistaking?

Answer (score 13):

While you can use aliased left joins, in this case you could also use a combination of grouping and conditional expressions:

```
select t.ticket_id,
       max(case when a.attr_type=1 then a.attr_val end) attr_val1,
       max(case when a.attr_type=2 then a.attr_val end) attr_val2,
       max(case when a.attr_type=3 then a.attr_val end) attr_val3
from ticket t
left join attr a on t.ticket_id = a.ticket_id
group by t.ticket_id
```

Answer (score 11):

You use table aliases

eg:

```
Select 
    ticket.ticket_id,  
    a1.attr_val as attr_val1,
    a2.attr_val as attr_val2,
    a3.attr_val as attr_val3
from ticket
    left join (select * from attr where attr_type=1) a1 on ticket.ticket_id=a1.ticket_id
    left join (select * from attr where attr_type=2) a2 on ticket.ticket_id=a2.ticket_id
    left join (select * from attr where attr_type=3) a3 on ticket.ticket_id=a3.ticket_id
```

Comment: This worked best for me because I had to do an INNER JOIN on tables I wanted to LEFT JOIN.