# Get username of the assigned and modified based on the user id

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns and in those 2 columns there's the User_ID and User_Name

Hi,

I have the columns UID and UName

```
*users*
| UID   |   UName   |
| 1     |   sam     |
| 2     |   corey   |
| 3     |   max     |
```

and then on some of our tables we just use the UID to retrieve who is assigned to that project or who modified it. Sometimes the ID for the Assigned and Modified columns is different and sometimes its not, the proj can be assigned to sam but max can also modify it.
The tables looks similar to this:

```
*table1*
| ProjName  |   Assigned_UID    |   Modified_UID    |
|   Proj1   |       2           |       3           |
|   Proj2   |       1           |       2           |
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is on this table above how can I get the username for those id's? 
I did it like

```
SELECT UName FROM users as u
INNER JOIN table1 as t
ON u.UID = t.Assigned_UID

GROUP BY UName
```

But it just showed me the list of the UName column, what I'm hoping to get for the output is like this

```
*table1*
| ProjName  |   Assigned_UID    |   Modified_UID    |
|   Proj1   |       corey       |       max         |
|   Proj2   |       sam         |       corey       |
```

I hope you guys can help me thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT ProjName, u1.UName as Assigned_UName, u2.Uname as Modified_UName 
FROM table1 as t
INNER JOIN users u1
ON u1.UID = t.Assigned_UID
INNER JOIN users u2
ON u2.UID = t.Modified_UID
```

Or you can see this question: [MySQL: How do I join same table multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561733/mysql-how-do-i-join-same-table-multiple-times)