# Select query - Joining same table multiple times to different columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I'm a SQL novice trying to write a select query that involves a join of multiple tables, with one table multiple times.

The relationships are shown below:
[image]

The output of the query I'm trying to achieve is this:

`Truck_ID|Pushbutton_ID|Trailer01_ID|Trailer02_ID|Trailer03_ID|Trailer04_ID|Trailer05_ID`

The joining of the tables `Trucks` and `Pushbutton_Assignments` is straightforward. The difficulty is joining the `Trailer_Assignment` table multiple times.

The structure of `Trailer_Assignments` is:

`Trailer_ID|Truck_ID|Order`

The `Trailer_ID` and `Truck_ID` fields have foreign key relationships with other tables. The `TrailerXX_ID` fields of the query are related to the `Order` field of the `Trailer_Assignment` table; all records with `Order == 1` have `Trailer_ID` put in `Trailer01_ID`, records with `Order == 2` to `Trailer02_ID` and so on.

I based my query from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561733/mysql-how-do-i-join-same-table-multiple-times?lq=1). It works for a single column but Access (I think) doesn't like subsequent columns.

Working Query code (single column):

`SELECT Trucks.ID, 
   Pushbutton_Assignment.Pushbutton_ID,
   Trailer_Assignment.Trailer_ID AS Trailer01_ID,
   Trailer_Assignment.Trailer_ID AS Trailer02_ID,
   Trailer_Assignment.Trailer_ID AS Trailer03_ID,
   Trailer_Assignment.Trailer_ID AS Trailer04_ID,
   Trailer_Assignment.Trailer_ID AS Trailer05_ID
FROM (Trucks LEFT JOIN Pushbutton_Assignment ON Trucks.ID = Pushbutton_Assignment.Truck_ID) LEFT JOIN Trailer_Assignment ON Trucks.ID = Trailer_Assignment.Truck_ID AND Trailer_Assignment.Order = 1;`

EDIT:

Non-working Query code (two column):

`SELECT Trucks.ID, 
   Pushbutton_Assignment.Pushbutton_ID,
   Trailer_Assignment.Trailer_ID AS Trailer01_ID,
   Trailer_Assignment.Trailer_ID AS Trailer02_ID,
   Trailer_Assignment.Trailer_ID AS Trailer03_ID,
   Trailer_Assignment.Trailer_ID AS Trailer04_ID,
   Trailer_Assignment.Trailer_ID AS Trailer05_ID
(((FROM (Trucks LEFT JOIN Pushbutton_Assignment ON Trucks.ID = Pushbutton_Assignment.Truck_ID))
LEFT JOIN Trailer_Assignment ON (Trucks.ID = Trailer_Assignment.Truck_ID AND Trailer_Assignment.Order = 1))
LEFT JOIN Trailer_Assignment ON (Trucks.ID = Trailer_Assignment.Truck_ID AND Trailer_Assignment.Order = 2));`

This is using Access 2003.

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: If I make a subsequent left join on `Trailer_Assignment`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access has all sorts of weird restrictions, such as difficulty handling constants in `LEFT JOIN` conditions.  So, just surrender and use correlated subqueries . . . you only want one value anyway:

```
select t.id, pba.pushbutton_id,
       (select top 1 ta.trailer_id from Trailer_Assignment as ta where ta.Truck_id = t.id and ta.order = 1
       ) as Trailer01_id,
       (select top 1 ta.trailer_id from Trailer_Assignment as ta where ta.Truck_id = t.id and ta.order = 2
       ) as Trailer02_id,
       (select top 1 ta.trailer_id from Trailer_Assignment as ta where ta.Truck_id = t.id and ta.order = 3
       ) as Trailer03_id,
       (select top 1 ta.trailer_id from Trailer_Assignment as ta where ta.Truck_id = t.id and ta.order = 4
       ) as Trailer04_id,
       (select top 1 ta.trailer_id from Trailer_Assignment as ta where ta.Truck_id = t.id and ta.order = 5
       ) as Trailer05_id
from Trucks as t LEFT JOIN
     Pushbutton_Assignment as pba
     on t.id = pba.truck_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does work as a select query, however, I now can't 'back-edit' (don't the know the technical term) through the result, whereas I could before (albeit with only one joined column).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the same table several times in your query, you need to provide an alias for each one:

```
SELECT Trucks.ID, 
   Pushbutton_Assignment.Pushbutton_ID,
   ta1.Trailer_ID AS Trailer01_ID,
   ta2.Trailer_ID AS Trailer02_ID,
   ta3.Trailer_ID AS Trailer03_ID,
   ta4.Trailer_ID AS Trailer04_ID,
   ta5.Trailer_ID AS Trailer05_ID
FROM (Trucks LEFT JOIN Pushbutton_Assignment ON Trucks.ID = Pushbutton_Assignment.Truck_ID) 
    LEFT JOIN Trailer_Assignment ta1 ON Trucks.ID = ta1.Truck_ID AND ta1.Order = 1
    LEFT JOIN Trailer_Assignment ta2 ON Trucks.ID = ta2.Truck_ID AND ta2.Order = 2
    LEFT JOIN Trailer_Assignment ta3 ON Trucks.ID = ta3.Truck_ID AND ta3.Order = 3
    LEFT JOIN Trailer_Assignment ta4 ON Trucks.ID = ta4.Truck_ID AND ta4.Order = 4
    LEFT JOIN Trailer_Assignment ta5 ON Trucks.ID = ta5.Truck_ID AND ta5.Order = 5;
```

Comment: Access query editor is complaining about a syntax error (missing operator), on the line `LEFT JOIN Trailer_Assignment ta1 ON Trucks.ID = ta1.Truck_ID AND ta1.Order = 1`. I think it's an Access issue (possibly).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Trucks.ID, 
   Pushbutton_Assignment.Pushbutton_ID,
   iif(ta.order = 1, ta.Trailer_ID, NULL) AS Trailer01_ID,
   iif(ta.order = 2, ta.Trailer_ID, NULL) AS Trailer02_ID,
   iif(ta.order = 3, ta.Trailer_ID, NULL) AS Trailer03_ID,
   iif(ta.order = 4, ta.Trailer_ID, NULL) AS Trailer04_ID,
   iif(ta.order = 5, ta.Trailer_ID, NULL) AS Trailer05_ID
FROM Trucks LEFT JOIN Pushbutton_Assignment 
ON Trucks.ID = Pushbutton_Assignment.Truck_ID 
LEFT JOIN Trailer_Assignment ta ON Trucks.ID = ta.Truck_ID
```

This is one more way to do it with `if` statements. You would need to refer to the table only once. Add a `where` clause if needed, to only look for orders 1,2,3,4 and 5.

Comment: Access query editor is complaining about a syntax error (missing operator) `case when ta.order = 1 then ta.Trailer_ID end`.

Comment: `case` is not valid in MS Access, changed it to `iif`. Try this.

Comment: This approach might work with GROUP BY, so you need a SUM() around iff()