# Replace value with Foreign Key's result

Tags: php, mysql, replace, alias

I have a table with all my invoice items as packages:

```
              Table: invoice_items

invoice_item_id | package_id | addon_1 | addon_2 | addon_3 | ...
----------------|------------|---------|---------|
        1       |     6      |    2    |    5    |    3    |
```

Then my other table:

```
              Table: addons

 addon_id |  addon_name  |        addon_desc        |
----------|--------------|--------------------------|
    1     | Dance Lights | Brighten up the party... |
    2     | Fog Machine  | Add some fog for an e... |
```

Instead of taking up space storing the addon name in my invoice_items table, I'd like to just include the addon_id in the addon_1, addon_2, etc columns.

How do I then get the name of the addon when doing a query for invoice_item rows?

Right now I just have it programmed into the page that if addon_id == 1, echo "Dance Lights", etc but I'd like to do it in the query. Here is my current query:

```
                  $invoice_items_SQL = "

                    SELECT invoice_items.*, packages.*
                    FROM `invoice_items`

                      INNER JOIN packages ON invoice_items.invoice_item_id = packages.package_id

                    WHERE `event_id` = \"$event_id\"

                    ";
```

So I'm able to do this with packages, but only because there's just one package_id per row, but there are up to 9 addons :(

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way of doing it is to [join onto the table multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561733/mysql-how-do-i-join-same-table-multiple-times). That's a bit naff though because you'll write almost the same thing 9 times.

Another, better way would be to restructure your tables - you need another table with 2 data columns: invoice_id and addon_id. You then need either an auto-inc primary column, or use both of those existing columns as a dual primary key. So this is a many-to-many junction table.

From there you can can query without having 9 repetitive joins, but you will get a row of each package for every addon it has (so if it has three addons it will appear three times in the results). And then from there you can use GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate the names of the addons into a single field so that you only get one row per invoice.

Comment: I like your second idea, however I'm thinking I'll probably want to stay away from a separate table, because that will make adding and deleting invoice_items much more difficult, cause I'd have to add multiple rows in different tables when I create, and search for and delete records from the addon table when I deleted an invoice_item. Maybe it will be worth it. Thanks so much for the ideas! How would I sort out the info from the joins to know which result is from which addon_id if I use your first suggestion?

Comment: You would alias the bits in the first SELECT with numbers. So, the JOINs would be aliased addson1, addons2, etc., then in the SELECT part you go addons1.addon_name AS addon1, addons2.addons_name AS addon2 and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand (I'm really new to PHP and mysql...how would that look as a query?