# Is it possible to join one table two times?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

my Problem is:
I want to display a table which contains the column "Customer".
This is a table where a collection of "Measures" is inside. The Problem is, there are two kinds of "Measures". They are also seperated in the databse table with a column called "type" (0 and 1).

And every "Measure" belongs to a "Customer", BUT for each "Measure" Type there is a different way to get the "Customer" Name:

This is the code:

```
$select = "blablabla..., c.name as customer";
$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->from("it_measure m");
```

It goes on for "Measures" with type 0:

```
$this->db->join("it_ma ma", "m.id = ma.measure", "LEFT OUTER");
$this->db->join("it_a a", "ma.a = a.id", "LEFT OUTER");
$this->db->join("it_i i", "a.i = i.id", "LEFT OUTER");
$this->db->join("it_customer c", "i.customer = c.id", "LEFT OUTER");
```

For "Measures" with Type 1:

```
$this->db->join("it_mf mf", "m.id = mf.mid", "LEFT OUTER");
$this->db->join("it_f f", "mf.fid= f.id", "LEFT OUTER");
$this->db->join("it_w w", "f.w = w.id", "LEFT OUTER");
$this->db->join("it_ga ga", "w.a = ga.id", "LEFT OUTER");
$this->db->join("it_customer c", "ga.customer = c.id", "LEFT OUTER");
```

So as you see i have different joins to get the customer Name for both types.
The  last join at both examples is the important one. I want to join on the same table (table_customer).
How can I realize it to Combine this query to get both joins into that one field customer.
I also tried it with a if query: if type 0.. else type 1.. but it doesn't work.

I would be soo glad if you could help me!
If anything is unclear please ask.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: How do I join same table multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561733/mysql-how-do-i-join-same-table-multiple-times)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just give each table a different alias.

Comment: but at least i need both results in the $select = "blablabla..., **c.name as customer";** line?

Comment: Yes, for example if you want to put name from the same table, just precede it with it's own alias that you gave it in the FROM statement. For example 1.name, 2.name

Comment: Thank you. I just changed to select = "blablabla..., **c1.name as customer, c2.name as customer";**. Now I get a value shown but ist the wrong value. I'll check my query

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I puzzled my head over this for days!

Comment: Glad to hear. I've been there before ^

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can join one table for two times. You can check this link.
[MySQL: How do I join same table multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561733/mysql-how-do-i-join-same-table-multiple-times)