# MySQL Query into single multi table join

Tags: mysql, join

End goal is to get tbl_output.output based on intent and slot attributes. I am currently handling it programmatically and would like to combine into one query if possible. I am open to restructuring any of the tables if needed.

```
SELECT id as intent_id FROM `tbl_intent` WHERE `name` = 'Car' 
SELECT id as slot_id1 FROM `tbl_slot` WHERE `name` = '2018' 
SELECT id as slot_id2 FROM `tbl_slot` WHERE `name` = 'Chevrolet'
SELECT id as slot_id3 FROM `tbl_slot` WHERE `name` = 'Corvette'
```

Example should return tbl_output ID 1 field "output".

```
SELECT 
    *,  
    output_id
FROM xref_intent_slot
    LEFT JOIN tbl_slot slot1 ON xref_intent_slot.slot_id=slot1.id AND slot1.name='2018'
    LEFT JOIN tbl_slot slot2 ON xref_intent_slot.slot_id=slot2.id AND slot2.name='Chevrolet'
    LEFT JOIN tbl_slot slot3 ON xref_intent_slot.slot_id=slot3.id AND slot3.name='Corvette'
WHERE `intent_id` = (SELECT id from tbl_intent WHERE `name` = 'Car')


+----+-----------+-----------+---------+------+------+------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+
| id | output_id | intent_id | slot_id | id   | name | id   | name      | id   | name     | output_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+------+------+------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |         1 |       1 |    1 | 2018 | NULL | NULL      | NULL | NULL     |         1 |
|  2 |         1 |         1 |       2 | NULL | NULL |    2 | Chevrolet | NULL | NULL     |         1 |
|  3 |         1 |         1 |       3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL      |    3 | Corvette |         1 |
|  4 |         2 |         1 |       4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL      | NULL | NULL     |         2 |
|  5 |         2 |         1 |       2 | NULL | NULL |    2 | Chevrolet | NULL | NULL     |         2 |
|  6 |         2 |         1 |       5 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL      | NULL | NULL     |         2 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+------+------+------+-----------+------+----------+-----------+
```

This should only return ID 1, 2, and 3 which is output_id 1. Then use that value to get the output from tbl_output?

Tables:

```
+-------------------+
| tbl_intent        |
| tbl_output        |
| tbl_slot          |
| xref_intent_slot  |
+-------------------+
```

Table: tbl_intent

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Car  |
+----+------+
```

Table: tbl_slot

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | 2018      |
|  2 | Chevrolet |
|  3 | Corvette  |
|  4 | 2017      |
|  5 | Camaro    |
+----+-----------+
```

Table: tbl_output

```
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| output | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+----+----------------+
| id | output         |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | Found Corvette |
|  2 | Found Camaro   |
+----+----------------+
```

Table: xref_intent_slot

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| output_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| intent_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slot_id   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
| id | output_id | intent_id | slot_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |         1 |         1 |       1 |
|  2 |         1 |         1 |       2 |
|  3 |         1 |         1 |       3 |
|  4 |         2 |         1 |       4 |
|  5 |         2 |         1 |       2 |
|  6 |         2 |         1 |       5 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: at least make an attempt.

Comment: Thanks. I have made plenty of attempts. I had 3 left joins going in a select on the xref_intent_slot table.  It kept returning way more rows than needed.

Comment: post your attempt, the results, and that was wrong with it.

Comment: I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I used this as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561733/mysql-how-do-i-join-same-table-multiple-times but I think I am falling short when I have to then use the result id to search the tbl_output table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    `output`
FROM tbl_output
WHERE
    id =
    (
        SELECT  
            output_id
        FROM xref_intent_slot
            LEFT JOIN tbl_slot slot1 ON xref_intent_slot.slot_id=slot1.id AND slot1.name='2018'
            LEFT JOIN tbl_slot slot2 ON xref_intent_slot.slot_id=slot2.id AND slot2.name='Chevrolet'
            LEFT JOIN tbl_slot slot3 ON xref_intent_slot.slot_id=slot3.id AND slot3.name='Corvette'
        WHERE `intent_id` = (SELECT id from tbl_intent WHERE `name` = 'Car') AND
            (slot1.name = '2018' OR
            slot2.name = 'Chevrolet' OR
            slot3.name = 'Corvette')
        group by output_id
        HAVING (count(output_id) = 3)
    )
LIMIT 0,1
```