# MySQL - Select statement of a table that contains 2 same-foreign-key columns

Tags: mysql

I can't really explain it in words because it is hard for me. I'll just show you what I need to accomplish.

So lets say I have 2 tables, admin and records.

admin table with sample data:

a_id | a_name

1    | haime

2    | joseph

Record table with sample data:

r_id | r_amount | r_a_create_by | r_a_update_by

1    | 99       | 1             | 2

So I have a transaction record that is created by admin with ID of 1 and updated by ID of 2. Now how can I make a select query of that? If I want the output of something like :

1 | 99 | haime | joseph

Comment: Btw the r_a_create_by and r_a_update_by are foreign key of a_id of admin table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561733/mysql-how-do-i-join-same-table-multiple-times

Comment: Thanks! I follow the link and learned the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the admin 2 times. This should work:

```
select r.r_id, r.r_amount, a.a_name, b.a_name 
from records r
join admin a on r.r_a_create_by = a.a_id 
join admin b on r.r_a_update_by = b.a_id
```